# Is there any known approach to change namespace but support old one in APIs

Tags: c#, namespaces, alias, forwarding

I have an DLL which has a name space Testuser.Standard and used by other people.

I want to change the namespace from Testuser.Standard to Test**U**ser.Standard and want to support old namespace which still used by other users.

Thanks in Advance

Timur

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may be interested in aliases, which can be applied to namespaces and types. Have a read through [using directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

It includes the following example for aliasing a namespace:

```cs
namespace PC
{
    // Define an alias for the nested namespace.
    using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
    class A
    {
        void M()
        {
            // Use the alias
            var mc = new Project.MyClass();
        }
    }
    namespace MyCompany
    {
        namespace Project
        {
            public class MyClass { }
        }
    }
}
```

And includes the following example for aliasing a type:

```cs
using System;

// Using alias directive for a class.
using AliasToMyClass = NameSpace1.MyClass;

// Using alias directive for a generic class.
using UsingAlias = NameSpace2.MyClass<int>;

namespace NameSpace1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "You are in NameSpace1.MyClass.";
        }
    }

}

namespace NameSpace2
{
    class MyClass<T>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "You are in NameSpace2.MyClass.";
        }
    }
}

namespace NameSpace3
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var instance1 = new AliasToMyClass();
            Console.WriteLine(instance1);

            var instance2 = new UsingAlias();
            Console.WriteLine(instance2);

        }
    }
}
// Output: 
//    You are in NameSpace1.MyClass.
//    You are in NameSpace2.MyClass.
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not. How can I define Testuser.Standard as alias in file
using Testuser.Standard=TestUser.Standard does not work

Comment: @Timur You can have multiple namespaces in an assembly. Move all your current code to `namespace TestUser.Standard`. In the same assembly, recreate `namespace Testuser.Standard` and alias all of the old classes `using Class1 = TestUser.Standard.Class1;` and so on. Would this not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could create child classes in the old namespace of all your updated classes in the new namespace.

Given that this is your old class:

```cs
namespace TestuserOld.Standard
{
    public class MyPublicClass
    {
        // Insert code here
    }
}
```

And you have moved it to the new namespace such that the class is now

```cs
namespace TestUser.Standard
{
    public class MyPublicClass
    {
        // Insert code here
    }
}
```

The old class must be updated as follows

```cs
namespace TestuserOld.Standard
{
    [Obsolete("This class in this namespace is obsolete. Please use the MyPublicClass class in the TestUser.Standard namespace.")]
    public class MyPublicClass : TestUser.Standard.MyPublicClass
    {
        // Should be empty
        // If the base class has a constructor, add an empty constructor and call the base constructor
    }
}
```